# Creating a complete the sentence game with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a complete the sentence game. The object of the game is the player has three words that they need to put in the correct order to complete the sentence. They can only use each word once

The code has to be reusable, there's going to be multiple items and this script will need to be reused multiple times throughout the game.

```js
$(".control").click(function() {
      let val = $(this).text();
      $(".blank").html(val);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <p>You will <span class="blank"></span> know <span class="blank"></span> 
    I <span class="blank"></span> you.</p>
    </div>

    <button class="control">never</button>
    <button class="control">know</button>
    <button class="control">love</button>
```

When using the code above only on span populates.

Comment: IDS are SINGULAR. You need to use a class or data attribute

Comment: tried it with classes before, still didnt work properly

Comment: @JasonSprague What *should* happen? Only the next empty one gets populated?

Comment: So amazing that after the edit it works....

Answer (score 2):

`$(".blank")` targets *all* elements with class `blank` on the page.

If you're looking for each button click to replace the *next empty* blank, instead use a combination of the [`:empty`](https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) and [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selectors.

To disable the button when it's clicked, set its `disabled` property to `true` using `.prop("disabled", true)`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".control").click(function() {
    let $this = $(this);
    let val = $this.text();
    $this.prop("disabled",true);
    $(".blank:empty:first").html(val);
  });
});
```

```css
span.blank {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>You will <span class="blank"></span> know <span class="blank"></span> I <span class="blank"></span> you.</p>
</div>

<button class="control">never</button>
<button class="control">know</button>
<button class="control">love</button>
```